# Class invariant: an object needs not-null one, and vice versa. What's the elegant way to provide?

Tags: javascript, oop

Let's suppose we should implement a doubly linked list. This data structure assumes a chain of `Link`'s and each of them has a connection with both previous and next ones. In due to I prefer not to deal with pesky null checks  (`if (previousLink !== null)`), it's worth taking as an invariant both previous and next links is never null. So it could seem like this:

```
class Link { 
  data;
  previousLink;
  nextLink;

  constructor(data, previousLink, nextLink) {
    this.data = data;
    this.previousLink = previousLink;
    this.nextLink = nextLink;
    this.checkClassInvariants();  
  }

  checkClassInvariants() {
    assert(this.previousLink !== null);
    assert(this.nextLink !== null);
  }

  insertPreviousLink(link) { ... checkClassInvariants(); }
  
  removePreviousLink() { ... checkClassInvariants(); }

  /* etc. */ 
}
```

All insert/remove routines don't bother with null checking, but rather they just tinker with object connections. Our sacriface for it is we have to implement some `BeginningLink` and `EndLink`. The former is aware that its `previousLink` is `null` and the latter is the same, but in relation to the `nextLink`. However, excluding these ones, the other part of assertions should still stand. It seems this objective is achievable through polymorphism of `checkClassInvariants()`:

```
class BeginningLink extends Link {
  constructor(nextLink) {
    super(new DummyData(), null, nextLink);
  }

  checkClassInvariants() {
    assert(this.nextLink !== null);
  }
}

class EndLink extends Link {
  constructor(previousLink) {
    super(new DummyData(), previousLink, null);
  }

  checkClassInvariants() {
    assert(this.previousLink !== null);
  }
}
```

And when our `LinkedList` tries to initialize itself with `BeginningLink` and `EndLink`, thier invariants will fail because at the moment `BeginningLink` is being creating no `EndLink` exists (or vica versa).

What's the elegant way to get around this snafu? Should I left out `checkClassInvariants()` (of the `Link` constructor at least) and put `LinkedList` in charge with not-null checking? But it would be better if a class itself explicitly claims its invariants, wouldn't be?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to address this, but it's hard to know which ones are appropriate to your situation. My first inclination would be to remove inheritance, and allow a Link to have a null previousLink and nextLink. If this is supposed to represent something like a LinkedList, I would think it should be perfectly normal to have a list with only one Link, representing both the beginning and the end. Is there something about your use case that makes that approach invalid?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior This approach causes we should do null-checking inside each of insert/remove method. Furthermore, if `LinkedList` is aware of two special links, it never should reassign its first and last links. Rather it just calls a needed method on them. It reduces the code.

Comment: And you don't need to support a LinkedList with only one link? Or an empty LinkedList? Or insert a new link at the start or end of the list? I think you'll find a more standard LinkedList implementation ends up being simpler, even though it requires you to handle nulls as a special case.